# php How to Insert, update and delete multiple checkboxes value in multiple rows database?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am working in codeigniter 3. I have to insert and update multiple checkboxes values in Database in multiple rows, not as comma-separated values. I am first deleting all records then inserting again and it's working. But in this case i have to delete all records first and then insert again. I want that if any record already exist then it update else insert. if any value is unchecked only then delete that record. Is there any way to update and records.

This is my form.

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/update-assignment">
<input type="hidden" id="inputName" name="propertyId" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $PropVal->property_id ?>">
<?php
                    $catArray = array("category_1"=>'Site',"category_2"=>'Unit',"category_3"=>'Areas');
                    $test_seq = 0;
                    foreach($catArray as $k=>$values)
                    {
                    
                    $userAssigned = getassignedUserData($PropVal->property_id,$values);
                                        
                    $arr = array(); 
                    foreach($userAssigned['data'] as $innerRow => $value)
                    {
                        $arr[$innerRow] =  $value['validation_code'];
                    }
                    foreach($usersListtoAssign as $key => $value) 
                    { 
                                
                                $uidandCode =  $value['user_id'].'--'.$value['validation_code'].'--'.$values;
                                $checked = "";
                                if(in_array($value['validation_code'],$arr))
                                {
                                    
                                    $checked = 'checked=checked';
                                }
                    
                    ?>
                    <div class="checklist-div"> 
                        <input type="checkbox" <?php echo $checked; ?> name="<?php echo $inputName."[]" ?>" id="chkbx<?= $value['user_id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $uidandCode ?>" class="chkbox select-<?= $values ?>" <?php echo $disable; ?>>&nbsp;<?php echo $value['first_name'].' '.$value['last_name'].'--'.$value['validation_code'] ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php } } ?>
</form>
```

Controller.php

```
<?php
function update_assignment()
{
    $inputs_ary = $this->input->post(); 
    $pId = $inputs_ary['propertyId'];
    
    if (isset($inputs_ary['validationCode1'])) 
            {
                    $codeVal = $inputs_ary['validationCode1'];
                    $category = 'Site';
                    
                    $this->PropertyModel->deletePropAssignNotExist($pId,$category);
                    foreach ($codeVal as $value) 
                    {
                        $explode = explode('--', $value);
                        $uId = $explode[0];
                        $validation_code = $explode[1];
                        
                        
                        $assignArr = array(
                                'user_id' => $uId,
                                'validation_code' => $validation_code,
                                'property_id' => $pId,
                                'category_name' => $category,
                                'created_on' => date('Y-m-d h:i:s')
                            );

                        $propAssignStatus = $this->PropertyModel->addPropertyAssignment($assignArr);

                        
                    }

                    
            }
            
            if(isset($inputs_ary['validationCode2']))
            {
                $codeVal2 = $inputs_ary['validationCode2'];
                $category = 'Unit Interior';
                $this->PropertyModel->deletePropAssignNotExist($pId,$category);             
                foreach($codeVal2 as $value)
                {
                    
                    $explode = explode('--',$value);
                    $uId = $explode[0];
                    $validation_code = $explode[1];
                                            
                        $assignArr = array(
                                'user_id' => $uId,
                                'validation_code' => $validation_code,
                                'property_id' => $pId,
                                'category_name' => $category,
                                'created_on' => date('Y-m-d h:i:s')
                            );

                        $propAssignStatus = $this->PropertyModel->addPropertyAssignment($assignArr);    
                    
                } 
                            
            
            }
}
```

PropertyModel.php

```
public function addPropertyAssignment($array)
{
    if(!empty($array) && count($array) > 0)
    {
        $res = $this->db->insert("property_assignment", $array);
        $result = custom_db_error_log($this->db);
        if($result['status'] == 1)
            $result['data'] = $this->db->insert_id();
        return $result;
    }
}

public function deletePropAssignNotExist($pId,$catName) 
{
    $sql = "delete from property_assignment where property_id='$pId' and category_name='$catName';";
    $res = $this->db->query($sql);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve updating or inserting multiple checkbox values in the database in CodeIgniter, you can use the following approach:

1. Modify the form to include hidden inputs for existing assignments and checkboxes for new assignments:

```php
<form role="form" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/update-assignment">
    <!-- Your other form inputs -->
    
    <?php foreach($catArray as $k => $values): ?>
        <?php
        $userAssigned = getassignedUserData($PropVal->property_id, $values);

        $existingAssignments = [];
        foreach ($userAssigned['data'] as $innerRow => $value) {
            $existingAssignments[] = $value['validation_code'];
        }

        foreach ($usersListtoAssign as $key => $value):
            $uidandCode = $value['user_id'].'--'.$value['validation_code'].'--'.$values;
            $checked = in_array($value['validation_code'], $existingAssignments) ? 'checked' : '';
        ?>
            <div class="checklist-div">
                <?php if (in_array($value['validation_code'], $existingAssignments)): ?>
                    <input type="hidden" name="existing_assignments[]" value="<?= $uidandCode ?>">
                <?php else: ?>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="new_assignments[]" value="<?= $uidandCode ?>" class="chkbox select-<?= $values ?>" <?php echo $disable; ?>>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?= $value['first_name'].' '.$value['last_name'].'--'.$value['validation_code'] ?>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</form>
```

2. Modify the controller to handle updating or inserting the assignments:

```php
function update_assignment()
{
    $inputs_ary = $this->input->post();
    $pId = $inputs_ary['propertyId'];

    // Handle existing assignments
    if (isset($inputs_ary['existing_assignments'])) {
        $existingAssignments = $inputs_ary['existing_assignments'];
        foreach ($existingAssignments as $value) {
            $explode = explode('--', $value);
            $uId = $explode[0];
            $validation_code = $explode[1];
            $category = $explode[2];

            $assignArr = array(
                'user_id' => $uId,
                'validation_code' => $validation_code,
                'property_id' => $pId,
                'category_name' => $category,
                'created_on' => date('Y-m-d h:i:s')
            );

            $propAssignStatus = $this->PropertyModel->updatePropertyAssignment($assignArr);
        }
    }

    // Handle new assignments
    if (isset($inputs_ary['new_assignments'])) {
        $newAssignments = $inputs_ary['new_assignments'];
        foreach ($newAssignments as $value) {
            $explode = explode('--', $value);
            $uId = $explode[0];
            $validation_code = $explode[1];
            $category = $explode[2];

            $assignArr = array(
                'user_id' => $uId,
                'validation_code' => $validation_code,
                'property_id' => $pId,
                'category_name' => $category,
                'created_on' => date('Y-m-d h:i:s')
            );

            $propAssignStatus = $this->PropertyModel->addPropertyAssignment($assignArr);
        }
    }

    // Redirect or show a message based on the result
}
```

3. Modify the model to handle updating existing assignments:

```php
public function updatePropertyAssignment($array)
{
    if (!empty($array) && count($array) > 0) {
        // Check if the assignment already exists in the database
        $existingAssignment = $this->db->get_where('property_assignment', [
            'user_id' => $array['user_id'],
            'property_id' => $array['property_id'],
            'category_name' => $array['category_name']
        ])->row();

        if ($existingAssignment) {
            // If the assignment exists, update it
            $this->db->where('id', $existingAssignment->id);
            $this->db->update('property_assignment', $array);
        } else {
            // If the assignment does not exist, insert it
            $this->db->insert('property_assignment', $array);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but it's not showing checked checkboxes, if user wants to uncheck the value again. Then delete will not work. I need delete option also.